# I've got fork of repo of npm package. How should I use it?

Tags: angular, git, ionic-framework, npm

So there's this repo of the original npm package: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar.

And its fork, which does not exist as a npm package, that I want to use in my project: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/tree/24feacfb29102ec61d6814281867e356fb1a9ee0.

I want to be able to use this fork in my Ionic3 project as I use the original package. How do I achieve this? Should I create my own npm package with the fork or is there some simpler way?

Comment: can't you just do a `npm install ionic2-calendar --save` like the docs state?

Comment: I want to install the fork, not the original package.

Comment: I assume you want to use the fork because you changed something in the original repository? Is it a general and useful change? If so, create a pull request to the original repository, maybe the owner will apply the change to the original repository!

Comment: This fork has been done by someone else and that person made pull request a long time ago and nothing happened with it. I really need these changes so that's why I am asking is there a way to use the fork as the original package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own npm package if you want to. If you have the infrastructure (build server + private npm repository) and you want to build on the forked repository I suggest you do that. Especially if other teams/projects will use your forked code.

If not, I would just include the original code in my project and treat it as my own code.
These files are probably the only ones you need to copy:

https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/tree/24feacfb29102ec61d6814281867e356fb1a9ee0/src

But keep in mind: if you copy the code, you'll have the merge the future changes to the original code yourself.

If you really don't want to copy the code, you can always take a look a git submodules.

Answer (score 5):

You can also npm install your specific fork from GitHub directly.  So, in your case:

```
npm install https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar.git --save
```